# Нужно получить количество подписчиков закрытого телеграмм канала

Tags: javascript, html, telegram, http

Нужно получить количество подписчиков закрытого телеграмм канала в любом виде, что бы можно было потом добавить на страницу сайта. Через GET запрос на *"https://api.telegram.org/botyour-bot-api-token/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=@channel-name"* не получиться так как нечего вписать в channel-name. Полный доступ к телеграм каналам есть

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что телеграмм отдаст вам данные о том, на что у вас нет прав?

Comment: Права могу получить, делаю для знакомого сайт, телеграм каналы его. Хочу просто узнать есть ли возможность при условии что есть полный доступ к каналу получить количество подписчиков для того что бы оно отображалось на сайте и автоматически обновлялось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения доступа через бота, пригласите вашего бота в закрытый канал, а затем предоставьте ему права на просмотр информации о пользователях (Read Members). Это всё делается в Панели Администратора. В противном случае доступ к данным будет невозможен.

Затем когда вы это сделали, нужно получить `chat_id`, для этого нужно сперва каналы сделать публичными и задать временный `channel_username`, и с помощью этого бота, узнать `chat_id`:

Вот как это будет выглядеть на примере `python` скрипта

```py
import telebot

bot_api_token = 'YOUR_BOT_API_TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_api_token)

# Замените 'YOUR_CHANNEL_USERNAME' на username вашего канала.
channel_username = 'YOUR_CHANNEL_USERNAME'

# Получаем информацию о канале и его chat_id.
channel_info = bot.get_chat(chat_id='@' + channel_username)

# Выводим chat_id канала.
print(f"Chat ID канала @{channel_username}: {channel_info.id}")
```

После того как вы выполните команду, бот вам выдаст ID чата. После чего, вы должны снова сделать канал приватным.

Теперь когда мы знаем chat_id, мы можем повторно выполнить запрос и убедиться, что теперь данные пользователей возвращаются, так как бот находится на канале и у него есть права администратора.

После всех этих действий, мы теперь знаем ID чата, и теперь можно смело отправлять запросы

```js
const botApiToken = 'YOUR_BOT_API_TOKEN';
// ID чата которую мы получили ранее
const chatId = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID';

// Создаем URL для запроса к API Telegram.
const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${botApiToken}/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=${chatId}`;

// Проверяем результат работы:
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.ok) {
      const subscribersCount = data.result;
      console.log(`Количество подписчиков: ${subscribersCount}`);
    } else {
      console.error(`Не удалось получить данные. Ошибка: ${data.description}`);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(`Произошла ошибка при выполнении запроса: ${error}`);
  });
```

---

**ВАЖНО!**

Не стоит отправлять этот запрос через фронтенд, так как токен бота будет виден всем! Это означает, что другие пользователи могут получить доступ к боту и его запросам. Поэтому лучше выполнять все эти запросы на стороне бэкенда, а через фронтенд отправлять запросы на получение данных бэкенду, и тот в свою очередь будет выполнять запросы телегарм боту, получать нужные данные и отправлять обратно на фронт.